# Calculate Xilinx MCS PROM checksum (signature)

Tags: xilinx, eeprom

Is it possibly to calculate the checksum (or signature in Xilinx terminology) for a Xilinx MCS file myself, i.e. without using promgen.exe or any other Xilinx tools?

This question has been asked many times on Xilinx's support forums and they're quite coy about it as if checksums are some secret IP they invented themselves. But I assumed it's a straightforward industry standard method, since third party tools can be used to read/write PROMs and calculate the checksums themselves in the process to verify.

If this can be done without using Xilinx's tools, can anyone provide details?

E.g. for `myfile.mcs`, being written to a PROM of size `Y` kB, with fill value `0xFF`, how would I replicate the checksum calculation that would come out of promgen.exe when making an MCS file?

I'm not looking for another existing software tool that will do this for me. I'm trying to understand the math involved so I can code something myself.

There's some tangential discussion [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446716/how-to-meaningfully-compare-xilinx-mcs-files) that does not get into details of checksum calculation.

Note that I'm NOT generating the MCS file using promgen.exe or I would just have that tool calculate the checksum for me.

Thanks.

Comment: In [this thread](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00007G0R4YSAV/crc32-in-mcsbitstream?language=en_US) the user _allanherriman_ assumes that _"it uses a CRC32C polynomial"_. CRC-32C poly=0x1EDC6F41, reversed=0x82F63B78

Comment: @Velvel Thanks for finding that, I hadn't seen that discussion. However, they're talking about CRCs embedded in the MCS/ bitstream itself. Which I think are different from the CRC for the full PROM (which is included in the cfi and prm files if you use Xilinx's promgen), i.e. what you'd check a read-back PROM against to confirm it was not corrupted.